# Python3, how to find crtf tocken in r.text?

Tags: python, client, python-requests, httpclient

I'm writing a client on Python and for authorisation I must send **POST** with login, password and CSRF token (I use requests).

I can see CSRF token in r.text, but i dont know how to find this string

> < input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="ImQyYzk5ZjVkY2U4NmI2Y2I5YTYxMGExMDdiOGRhNTZhNzllYzY5NDUi.DG35rw.dTzyTeP7giMkInma1vsty9GaKQA" />

and copy csrf tocken to variable **csrftoken** and send like this

```
r = requests.post(url,data=dict(login=123,password=123, csrf_token=csrftoken))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
input_tag = soup.find("input", {"name":"csrf_token"})
csrf_token = input_tag.get("value")
```